# Pivot by group and merge in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have two dataframes, `company_df` and `car_df`. A company can have multiple cars and a car can only have one company.

**Company_DF**

```
   Company_ID Company_Name
0           1         Ford
1           2       Holden
2           3          Kia
```

**Car_DF**

```
   Company_ID  Car_ID   Car_Name
0           1       1     Falcon
1           1       2      Focus
2           2       1  Commodore
3           3       1    Sorento
4           3       2        Rio
5           3       2   Sportage
```

**The Rio and Sportage have the same Car_ID on purpose, about 1 percent of my rows have this issue, it is not something I can change in my data source.**

I would like to pivot each group of cars, by company, so that the cars are all on one line. For example.

```
   Company_ID Company_Name  Car_ID_1 Car_Name_1  Car_ID_2 Car_Name_2  Car_ID_3  Car_Name_3
0           1         Ford         1     Falcon       2        Focus       NaN         NaN
1           2       Holden         1  Commodore       NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN
2           3          Kia         1    Sorento         2        Rio         2    Sportage
```

What I have at the moment works for 99 of the rows, is slow, and a messy way of doing it. But I'm not sure how to improve on it.

```
import pandas as pd
company_df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'Ford'], [2, 'Holden'], [3, 'Kia']], columns=['Company_ID', 'Company_Name'])
car_df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 'Falcon'], [1, 2, 'Focus'], [2, 1, 'Commodore'], [3, 1, 'Sorento'], [3, 2, 'Rio'], [3, 2, 'Sportage']], columns=['Company_ID', 'Car_ID', 'Car_Name'])
for i in range(1, 3): # looping through car ids up to maximum, I don't want to do this though
    car_by_id_df = car_df[car_df.Car_ID==i] # select cars with current loop iterator/index
    car_by_id_df.columns = map(lambda col: '{}_{}'.format(col, i), car_by_id_df.columns) # rename all columns with ID as suffix, 
    car_by_id_df.rename(columns={'Company_ID_{}'.format(i): 'Company_ID'}, inplace=True) # Rename joining column back to original
    company_df = company_df.merge(right=car_by_id_df, on='Company_ID', how='left') # Merge
print(company_df)
```

This returns the following. Note that `Kia` is duplicated because of `Rio` and `Sportage` have the same id. I can't change the data in the `Car_ID` column, and I'm not sure how else to pivot the dataframe.

```
   Company_ID Company_Name  Car_ID_1 Car_Name_1  Car_ID_2 Car_Name_2
0           1         Ford         1     Falcon       2        Focus
1           2       Holden         1  Commodore       NaN        NaN
2           3          Kia         1    Sorento       2          Rio
3           3          Kia         1    Sorento       2     Sportage
```

How can I pivot my `car_df` by group and merge onto `company_id`?

Comment: The ordering of the cars in the final dataframe does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```py
res=Car_DF.set_index("Company_ID").stack().to_frame()

res["sub_no"]=res.groupby(level=[0,1]).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)

res=res.reset_index(level=1)
res["level_1"]=res["level_1"].str.cat(res["sub_no"], sep="_")

res=res.drop("sub_no", axis=1).set_index("level_1", append=True).unstack("level_1")
res.columns=map(lambda x: x[1], res.columns)
res=res[sorted(res.columns, key=lambda x: x.split("_")[-1])]
res=Company_DF.merge(res, on="Company_ID", how="left")
```

Outputs:

```py
  Company_ID Company_Name  ... Car_ID_3 Car_Name_3
0          1         Ford  ...      NaN        NaN
1          2       Holden  ...      NaN        NaN
2          3          Kia  ...        2   Sportage
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll apply it to my larger problem and let you know how it goes

Comment: I'm unable to test this answer as it is too resource intensive. The two input dataframes are ~4GB, but the program is exceeding the 64GB the machine has. After 6 hours of processing, it still did not complete. I'll look for another method that can handle large datasets.

Comment: I'd look at it more from the perspective of the output- you will produce more data at the end, which will be expressed by these ```nan```-s under both `Car_ID` and `Car_Name` - so especially, if you have small amount of companies with way more cars than others, you might get the size blows away. Maybe it's worth restricting the max number of cars shown? (From my code that would be saying e.g. ```res=res.loc[res['sub_no'].lt(100)]``` before the line where I drop it)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. I don't like the use of the for loop but it does work, and relatively fast.

```
import pandas as pd
Company_DF = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'Ford'], [2, 'Holden'], [3, 'Kia']], columns=['Company_ID', 'Company_Name'])
Car_DF = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 'Falcon'], [1, 2, 'Focus'], [2, 1, 'Commodore'], [3, 1, 'Sorento'], [3, 2, 'Rio'], [3, 2, 'Sportage']], columns=['Company_ID', 'Car_ID', 'Car_Name'])

Car_DF['rank'] = Car_DF.groupby(['Company_ID']).cumcount() + 1
for ranking_number in range(Car_DF['rank'].min(), Car_DF['rank'].max()):
    Ranked_Car_DF = Car_DF[Car_DF['rank']==ranking_number].copy()
    Ranked_Car_DF.columns = map(lambda col: '{}_{}'.format(col, ranking_number), Ranked_Car_DF.columns)
    Ranked_Car_DF.rename(columns={'Company_ID_{}'.format(ranking_number): 'Company_ID'}, inplace=True)
    Company_DF = Company_DF.merge(right=Ranked_Car_DF, on='Company_ID', how='left')
print(Company_DF)
```